# invoke own private method for the result in jmockit

Tags: java, invoke, jmockit

I got this code in my junit:

```
new NonStrictExpectations(mPersonEvaluator) {
  {
    invoke(mPersonEvaluator, "doEvaluatePerson", withAny(String.class), withAny(Integer.class), withAny(Integer.class));
    result = doEvaluatePerson((String)any, (Integer)any, (Integer)any);  
  }
};
```

I want to generate the result from my private method `doEvaluatePerson((String)any, (Integer)any, (Integer)any);` everytime the method doEvaluatePerson is called in the business logic of `mPersonEvaluator`.
The invoke works fine but the result is only calculated once during the setup of the `junit` and that result is null.
My question is how can I declare such kind of usecase in `jmockit` so that the mock uses my private method?

Thank in advance

Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I found the answer.
one possible solution is to use a `Delegator` like this:

```
   result = new Delegate<PersonArt>() {
      PersonArt delegator(String pShortName, Integer pOld, Integer pSize)
      {
         return doEvaluatePersonArt(pShortName, pOld, pSize);
      }
   };
```

works pretty fine.